# media file created using install4j for Windows Web Server 2008 32 bit OS is causing error "entry point K32EnumProcessModules could not be located"

Tags: install4j

I am facing error "entry point K32EnumProcessModules could not be located" on *Windows Web Server 2008 32 bit* for media/installer created using **install4j**. It occurs right after I launch the installer.
I am using **install4j version 8**.

[PFA image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaMcd.png)

I analyzed the error and found that, function K32EnumProcessModules is not available on Windows Web Server 2008. It is available from Windows Server 2008 R2 onwards. Does this mean media/installer created using install4j, does not support this OS? Also, if that's the case then are there any possible fixes/workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a message from "java.exe", not from a launcher created by install4j. Likely this happens when the native install4j launcher tries to determine the version number of the bundled JRE which does not support running on such an old Windows version.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details. Do you think downgrading bundled JRE version will help here?

Comment: Yes, this could help

Comment: Downgrading bundled JRE version resolved issue for above OS.
Thanks @Ingo Kegel for your quick help.